# Ruby on rails - Adding/ Removing cookie when user is on new post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

I have a gallery-like application where user can add albums. In my application I add a `cookie` called `__nr` when user comes to view a album if browser doesn't have `__nr` cookie.

*This is how I do it*

```
rand = rand(1..999)
cookies[:__nr] = {value: rand, expires: 10.minutes.from_now} if cookies[:__nr].blank?
```

This works fine, but what I want to achieve is, when they go to a new album/`album_path` I want to add a new random number as `cookie value`.

What I have now is `expires: 10.minutes.from_now`, but I want to change `cookie value` when they are on a new album path.

I know I can add `javascript` to remove the cookie when click on some buttons but I don't want to use `javascript function` and want to handle it from my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `cookies.delete :__nr` what you're looking for? You can use a `before_action` method in your controller to limit which controller actions delete that cookie.

For example:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  before_action :delete_the_cookie, only: [:new]

  def delete_the_cookie
    cookies.delete :__nr
  end
end
```

That will only delete the cookie for your `new` controller action.